# QWebview: manage a local SWF using Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, flash, qwebview

I'm using a QWebview in a QT Application to open a local HTML. 
HTML page contains an SWF movie an I manage it externally using Javascript.

I.e. Here how I open HTML page using in C++:

```
/* ... */
ui->webview->setUrl(QURL::fromLocalFile(indexHtmlPath);
```

Inside HTML page I have this Javacript code:

```
/* ... */
swfObject.GotoFrame(10)
```

HTML page works fine in a web server but local version give me an error: "Error calling method on NPObject.".

It seems a Flash security policy but how can I avoid it?

I'm using QT 5.2.1 but I have the same error opening local page using Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved!
I added in mms.cfg this row:

```
LocalFileLegacyAction = 1
```

mms.cfg is in:

- /etc/adobe (Linux)
- %systemroot%\System32\Macromed\Flash (Win32)
- %systemroot%\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash (Win64)
- app support/Macromedia (Mac)

If it doesn't exists, you can create it (see [Adobe Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c95.html)).